# reading real database to reset password swift

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to let user reset their email password, but it keep telling that the email not exist.

my real database:

```
{
  "users" : {
    "3fnXK15E8QVzf0tec1SpViLyv5w2" : {
      "Account Info" : {
        "email" : "test@gmail.com",
        "name" : "nada"
      },
      "id" : "-M7n2Hr5w5xDuVKkhg_b",
      "role" : "buyer",
      "uid" : "3fnXK15E8QVzf0tec1SpViLyv5w2"
    }
  }
}
```

my code:

```
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child("Account Info")

        ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: self.txtEmail.text!).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            if snapshot.exists(){
                Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: self.txtEmail.text!)
}else{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how you indicate the presence of the `Account Info` node in your JSON. You now have that in the path that you query, which means Firebase looks for a node `/users/Account Info` and queries *that*. And since `/users/Account Info` doesn't exist, that query has no results.

What you instead is to make `Account Info` part of the path of the property that you order/query on. So something like:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")

ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "Account Info/email").queryEqual(toValue: self.txtEmail.text!).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    if snapshot.exists(){
        Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: self.txtEmail.text!)
    }
```